# How do I put the value into txt file(file contains blank spaces)? Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have problem with data in the file. Data in the text file looks like:

```
ADSE64E...Mobile phone.....................                           
EDW8......Unknown item.....................                           
CAR12.....Peugeot 206 with red colour......            
GJ........Parker model 2...................                         
Por887W8..Black coffe from Peru............
```

The dots represents blank spaces. First column is Product_Code (long 1-10) and second (long 1-255) is Description. All i need is:

```
ADSE64E;Mobile phone                           
EDW8;Unknown item                          
CAR12;Peugeot 206 with red colour           
GJ;Parker model 2.                         
Por887W8;Black coffe from Peru
```

My solusions are:

1. First column get to the variable (and same process with second column) and merge both variables to one.. But i dont know how..

   $variabletxt = get-content C:\Product.txt

   $firstcolumn = $variablestxt.substring(1,10)

   $secondcolumn = $variablestxt.substring(10)

   $final = ???
2. Replace blank spaces but problem is that product_code may by long 1-10.

Have you any suggestion how I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split your sting then replace "more than one space" with nothing :

```
gc file.txt |%{
($_.substring(0,9)  -replace "[ ]{2,}","")+";"+($_.substring(10,254)  -replace "[ ]{2,}","")+";"
}
```

Comment: you're welcome please remember to mark post as answered if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

Remove trailing dots with the TrimEnd method and replace the ones that left.

```
Get-Content C:\Product.txt | 
Foreach-Object { $_.TrimEnd() -replace '^([^\s]+)(\s+)(.+)$','$1;$3'}

ADSE64E;Mobile phone
EDW8;Unknown item
CAR12;Peugeot 206 with red colour
GJ;Parker model 2
Por887W8;Black coffe from Peru
```

Per @Kayasax comment (thanks!), if code length is 10 characters long there will be no space between the first and second column, so it may be safer to use this instead:

```
Get-Content C:\Product.txt | 
Foreach-Object { '{0};{1}' -f $_.Substring(0,10).Trim(), $_.Substring(10).Trim() }
```

Comment: . stands for space in OP question

Comment: Yeah, that better ofc. Just fix it to: `$_.TrimEnd() -replace "[ ]{2,}",";"`. :)

Comment: if product code is 10 chars long then there will be no space beetween 1st and second column..

Comment: Thanks again dude, added a second solution.